# read array key from inside array

Tags: php, arrays

Can I read array key from inside the array itself , please to suggest php functions and not foreach loops , as I am trying to avoid loops as much as possible?

code looks like this :

```
array_fill_keys(array('a','b','c', 'd'),array(
    'action'=>'getUserLongTermCategoriesAction',
    'params'=> 'place key here',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this.

```
    $arr = array('a','b','c','d');
    $temp =  array_map(function ($keys) {
        return array(
            'action'=>'getUserLongTermCategoriesAction',
            'params'=> $keys,
        );
    }, $arr);
    $result = array_combine($arr, $temp);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [action] => getUserLongTermCategoriesAction
            [params] => a
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [action] => getUserLongTermCategoriesAction
            [params] => b
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [action] => getUserLongTermCategoriesAction
            [params] => c
        )

    [d] => Array
        (
            [action] => getUserLongTermCategoriesAction
            [params] => d
        )

)
```

Comment: I am trying to keep array keys using array_fill_keys as u see so keys are a,b,c,d . is it possible in simple way to achieve that too ? @walkingRed